# How to search for string in a list and focus on specific array it's in

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm currently struggling with this part of python... I understand how to form a 2d array but I don't get what piece of code will allow me to focus on a single line.

my array is like this: `array=[["1", "Number 1", 1.00],["2", "Number 2", 2.00],["3", "Number 3", 3.00]]`

I wanted to search the array for a specific string and grab other integers from within the array but I'm pretty confused since I started joining together some code myself but to no avail... 
Thanks alot for any help

Comment: That's a list, not an array. Totally different things in Python. Please update title, body and tags.

Comment: @MadPhysicist How a list is different from an array apart from the name in Python?

Comment: Different data structure, memory layout, methods, class, etc, @VisioN

Comment: @MadPhysicist How do you define an array in Python, assuming that the list is a `list` (or `[]` in literal notation)?

Comment: @VisioN module `array` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html) in Python is reserved for storing numeric values, list is general

Comment: @VisioN. There are also implementations like numpy and xarray

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic since OP is literally asking how to index a list, likely the next paragraph in the tutorial after making it

Comment: @AndrejKesely Well, in the context of builtin Python containers, it's not a big mistake to call a list an "array". And we all understand that the OP did mean exactly this and not the advanced library for efficient memory manipulation. So I would not stick to the way how the learner calls basically an array, hence was my question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the fact I'm new to python. I thought that a systems engineer would be able to work out what I was saying and suggest what was wrong and give an answer... It's pretty depressing how this is a forum for people to learn and find out things whilst there are people like u who just try to point out the mistakes and do nothing about it to fix them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the integers or how you want to match the string, but something like this should work:

```py
# assume `query` is the string to find
for inner in array:
    if inner[1] == query:
        i = int(inner[2])
        # do something with `i`
```